# Не могу запустить браузер с помощью selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

Всем привет.
Может кто-то сталкивался с такими ошибками:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 105.0.5195.52 (412c95e518836d8a7d97250d62b29c2ae6a26a85-refs/branch-heads/5195@{#853}) on port 61660
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61670/devtools/browser/47e9ded2-ab3a-4fa6-8132-f08a9b86f63b
[7676:1124:0912/210801.041:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [21:08:01.046] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: ╧Ёшёюхфшэхээюх ъ ёшёЄхьх єёЄЁющёЄтю эх ЁрсюЄрхЄ. (0x1F)
[7676:1124:0912/210801.090:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [21:08:01.091] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: ╧Ёшёюхфшэхээюх ъ ёшёЄхьх єёЄЁющёЄтю эх ЁрсюЄрхЄ. (0x1F)
[7676:1124:0912/210801.186:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [21:08:01.185] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1164 RequestRadioAccessAsync failed: RadioAccessStatus::DeniedByUserWill not be able to change radio power.
```

Установелн NET 6.0

Что может быть не так и как исправить?
Система win10

Comment: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._

Comment: А что, не работает? USB тут при чем?

Comment: USB это стандартная ошибка selenium, она всегда вылетает. Больше это волнует: [7676:1124:0912/210801.186:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [21:08:01.185] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1164 RequestRadioAccessAsync failed: RadioAccessStatus::DeniedByUserWill not be able to change radio power

Comment: А зачем вам Bluetooth? Браузер может использовать его для определения месстаположения или воспроизведения аудио например.

Comment: Мне он нафиг не нужен, но прога дальше не идет, после того как показывает данные ошибки. Может просто файла не хватает?